# Why can't I assign a variable to a hash entry in Perl?

Tags: perl

Sorry, I'm super rusty with Perl. See the following code:

```
foreach my $hash (keys %greylist)
{
  $t = $greylist{$hash};
  print $greylist{$hash}[4] . "\n";
  print $t[4] . "\n";
}
```

Why does `$t[4]` evaluate to a blank string, yet `$greylist{$hash}[4]` which should be the same thing evaluates to an IP address?

Comment: `use strict` would have told you what your error is. Always `use strict; use warnings;` at the top of every Perl program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$greylist{$hash}` contains an array reference. When you do:

```
print $greylist{$hash}[4];
```

Perl [automatically treats it as an array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule) but when you do:

```
$t = $greylist{$hash};
print $t[4];
```

You're assigning the array reference to a scalar variable, `$t`, then attempting to access the 5th element of another variable, `@t`. `use strict` would give you an error in this scenario.

Use [the arrow operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator), `->`, to dereference:

```
$t = $greylist{$hash};
print $t->[4];
```

[`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Using-References) has a note about this:

> If `$aref` holds a reference to an array, then `$aref->[3]` is the fourth element of the array. Don't confuse this with `$aref[3]` , which is the fourth element of a totally different array, one deceptively named `@aref` . `$aref` and `@aref` are unrelated the same way that `$item` and `@item` are.